# Error in if (is.na(n) || n > 65536L) stop("size cannot be NA nor exceed 65536")

Tags: r, distance, hierarchical-clustering, dimensionality-reduction

I want to perform hierarchical clustering on an object generated by `Rtsne()`. `Rtsne` gives a list, that I converted to a `data.frame`.  Then I used `dist`on it, followed by `hclust()`. 
But this gives me the error `Error in if (is.na(n) || n > 65536L) stop("size cannot be NA nor exceed 65536") : 
 missing value, where TRUE/FALSE are needed`

No `NA` values are in any object

```
tsne <- Rtsne(df[!duplicated(df), -14],check_duplicates=F)
tsne <- as.data.frame(tsne)
tsne_dist <- dist(tsne,method="euclidean")
hc_tsne <- hclust(tsne,method = "average")
class(tsne)
[1] "list"
> any(is.na(tsne))
[1] FALSE
```

I know that is not a real repex. But I cannot generate a dummy example and established example datasets like `iris` could not reproduce the error. Nonetheless, I hope somebody can help me.
I have seen [Hierarchical clustering using cosine distance in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52391558/hierarchical-clustering-using-cosine-distance-in-r)

Comment: Your approach makes no sense to me on multiple levels... have you looked at what is the Rtnse object that you are trying to cluster and what coercing it to a `data.frame` does? If you want to cluster the 2D representation found in the Y slot, then pick that slot only. If you want to cluster the dist object, cluster `tsne_dist`, not `tsne`. If you successfully coerced tsne to data.frame in your code, then it should not be of class list anymore...